# Windows 7 backup disk usage

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

Am I correct in saying that Windows 7 backup does not automatically retire older backups when it's backup disk gets full?  As in, when the disk gets full, the backups stop?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are correct, based on my anecdotal observation of a "disk full" message when doing backups on Windows 7 RC1. Things may have changed though, but I've not run out of space since then.